# Python - while loop in try and catch

Tags: python, while-loop, try-catch

I work on hardware. The variables are physical and they can change at any moment
and I want to write a while-loop in try and catch,
but I want to do this shorter.

I wrote this:

```
try:
    local_factory_param_multi_burn = _itwo_cnc_instance.get_parameters("factory_param_multi_burn")
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception(f"Failed to get factory_param_multi_burn. {e}")
while local_factory_param_multi_burn != 3:
    try:
        local_factory_param_multi_burn = _itwo_cnc_instance.get_parameters("factory_param_multi_burn")
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to get factory_param_multi_burn. {e}")
```

I want that as long as the GET function does not return 3, the loop will continue, and the loop will break only when the GET function returns 3.

I want to do this:

```
try:
    while _itwo_cnc_instance.get_parameters("factory_param_multi_burn") != 3
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception(f"Failed to get factory_param_multi_burn. {e}")
```

Comment: Format the code properly.

Comment: I don't know to do this

Comment: khelwood did it for you. In the second snippet try to append `: pass` to the `while ...` line

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var = _itwo_cnc_instance.get_parameters("factory_param_multi_burn")
while (var != 3):
    try:
        var = _itwo_cnc_instance.get_parameters("factory_param_multi_burn")
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to get factory_param_multi_burn. {e}")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't `raise` exceptions, you can prevent breakint out of the while loop. Eg:

```py
while local_factory_param_multi_burn != 3: 
  try: 
    local_factory_param_multi_burn = _itwo_cnc_instance.get_parameters("factory_param_multi_burn") 
  except Exception as e: 
    print(f"Failed to get factory_param_multi_burn. {e}")
```

This will now loop forever, until
`local_factory_param_multi_burn == 3`